# Not able to delete row from second table when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to remove specific row when checkbox is unchecked from first table. It seems like index attribute is not working in  **else part**
I am cloning rows from first table to second.

html for first table:

```
<table id="vergeTable" class="pure-table dataTable table-bordered vergeTable rowClick" role="grid">
   <thead>
      <tr role="row">
         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" align="left">Navn</th>
         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" align="left">Mandat</th>
         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" align="left">Status</th>
         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" align="left">Regnskapsplikt</th>
         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" align="left">Dato startet</th>
         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" align="left">Dato til</th>
         <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" align="left">Velg</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="odd" role="row">
         <td>Alfred Psa Asker</td>
         <td>Ivareta personens interesser innenfor det personlige og økonomiske området</td>
         <td> Tidligere </td>
         <td>Ordinær</td>
         <td>10.07.2013</td>
         <td>01.10.2016</td>
         <td class="contentCenter">
            <input id="regnskapVerge0" class="transForm1Dot5 valgtVerge" name="regnskap.regnskapVerge[0].velgVerge" value="true" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
            <input name="_regnskap.regnskapVerge[0].velgVerge" value="on" type="hidden">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd vergeDetailRow" role="row">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

html for second table:

```
<table id="vergeTable2" class="pure-table dataTable table-bordered vergeTable rowClick" role="grid">
   <thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="message2" style="display: none;">
      <tr class="odd vergeDetailRow" role="row">
         <td>Alfred Psa Asker</td>
         <td>Ivareta personens interesser innenfor det personlige og økonomiske området</td>
         <td> Tidligere </td>
         <td>Ordinær</td>
         <td>10.07.2013</td>
         <td>01.10.2016</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd vergeDetailRow" role="row">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

here is js code:

```
popuateFinalVergeTable: function(e) {
    $("#vergeTable input:checkbox.valgtVerge").change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".message2").hide();
            //Cache cloned object in a variable
            var clone = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
            //Remove checkbox
            clone.find('td').eq(6).remove();
            //Append it
            clone.appendTo("#vergeTable2");
        } else {
            var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
            var findRow = $("#vergeTable2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
            findRow.remove();
            var checks = $('#vergeTable').find(':checked').length;
            if (!checks) {
                $(".message2").show();
            }
        }
    }).change();
 },
```

Comment: show your html please

Comment: where is the data-index on tr?

Comment: @ScanQR, when I was copying from front end through firebug it was visible, I think it was auto generated with values were entered at run time, I also tried removing using class name **'odd vergeDetailRow'**, but unsuccessfull

Comment: Every tr in second table has odd vergeDetailRow so it is incorrect.

Comment: @SanQR,To delete rows dynamically, It is set to same class using $(this).closest("tr") , It will pick which row to delete

Comment: for other table is not known which row in table one was referred. Other table will give all tr with same class names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the reason why you should call `.change()` after the change event listener.

As for the missing `data-index`, `.data()` sets background data that is handled purely by jQuery - it does not set HTML attributes, so you wont be able to access it through `$('tr').attr('data-index')` but only with `$('tr').data('index')`.

Take a look at this code and edit according to your needs

```
$("#table1 input:checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        var clone = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
        clone.find('td').eq(1).remove();
        clone.appendTo("#table2");
    } else {
        var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-pk");
        $("#table2 tr[data-pk='" + index + "']").remove();
    }
});
```

Take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sj08fk7z/

Comment: How can we access data-pk? I mean it may not be data-pk in my code.

Comment: Since you said that `data-index` was generated at run time, I assumed it was used by some other plugin, so it is better to rely on custom attribute. In my case I used `data-pk` but you can use whatever `data-*` you prefer

Comment: If you want to set `data-pk` attribute, you just do `$('tr').attr('data-pk', new_value);`